# IonIcon.d.ts(4, 5)El tipo esperado procede de la propiedad "name",que se declara aquí en el tipo "IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

Soy un tanto nuevo con typescript y se me presentó un error:

> (property) name: "logo-github" | "logo-linkedin" | "mail-outline" | "search" | "repeat" | "link" | "at" | "body" | "code" | "map" | "menu" | "time" | "ellipse" | "filter" | "image" | "stop" | "text" | ... 1314 more ... | "woman-sharp"
>
> El tipo 'string' no se puede asignar al tipo '"logo-github" | "logo-linkedin" | "mail-outline" | "search" | "repeat" | "link" | "at" | "body" | "code" | "map" | "menu" | "time" | "ellipse" | "filter" | "image" | "stop" | "text" | ... 1314 more ... | "woman-sharp"'.ts(2322)
>
> IonIcon.d.ts(4, 5): El tipo esperado procede de la propiedad "name", que se declara aquí en el tipo "IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes & { name: "logo-github" | "logo-linkedin" | "mail-outline" | ... 1328 more ... | "woman-sharp"; size?: "small" | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }"

Estoy usando una librería para los icons = https://ionic.io/ionicons

Inicialicé mi proyecto con Vite, react-typescript

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import IonIcon from "@reacticons/ionicons"

function Contact() {

  interface ContactType {
    icon: string;
    text: string;
  }

 

const contact: ContactType[] = [
    {icon: 'logo-github', text: 'GitHub', link: 'link'},
    {icon: 'logo-linkedin', text: 'Linkedin', link: 'link'},
    {icon: 'mail-outline', text: 'Correo', link: 'link'},
  ]


  return (
    <section id='contact' className="py-10 px-3 text-white">
      <div className="text-center mt-8">
        <h3 className="text-4xl font-semibold">Contacta<span className="text-cyan-600">me</span></h3>
        <p className="text-gray-400 mt-3 text-lg">Ponerse en Contacto</p>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-16 flex md:flex-row flex-col gap-6 max-w-5xl bg-gray-800 p-6 rounded-lg mx-auto">
        <form className="flex flex-col flex-1 gap-6" action="">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Tu Nombre" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Tu Correo" />
          <textarea placeholder="Tu Mensage" rows={10}></textarea>
          <button className="btn-primary w-fit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
        </form>
        <div className="">
          <div className="flex gap-4 w-fit items-center">
            <div>
              {
                contact?.map((contact, i: number) => (
                  <div key={i} className='min-w-[4rem] min-h-[4rem] flex items-center justify-center text'>
                    <a href={contact.link}>
                      <IonIcon name={contact.icon}></IonIcon> // <--- El error ocurre aca en name
                    </a>
                  </div>
                ))
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Contact
```

Comment: Estas llamando un nombre de icono erroneo en la propiedad de `name` en el componente de `IonIcon` , busca los nombres correcto de los iconos.

Comment: Verifique bien los nombres de los iconos, y si están correctos,  los nombres serian <ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>, <ion-icon name="logo-github"></ion-icon>, <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>, estas etiquesar son de html, pero en react se instale las dependencias desde acá: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reacticons/ionicons, para que me diera el componente adecuado para su uso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución resulta con el siguiente código:

resulta que la propiedad name. sus tipos son específicos y no se le puede pasar un tipo primitivo de forma explícita como 'string' en mi caso

```html
function Contact() {

type IconType = 'logo-github' | 'logo-linkedin' | 'mail-outline' // solo agregue esta linea de codigo donde estableci diferentes pocibilidades de typo que soporta la variable icon

  interface ContactType {
    icon: IconType; // establecí el tipo creado 
    text: string;
  }

... }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo funciona tu código. Puede que para ti sea obvio, pero para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar, no. Lee [answer]. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.